# Z80: How to add 16 and 8 bit registers?

Tags: assembly, z80

How do you add a 16 and a 8 bit register with carry (for example, HL, and A)?

Comment: OMG. I haven't done any Z80 programming since POKE-ing machine code into a Sinclair ZX-80 REM statement in 1980 or so. My loss, it's an excellent processor for some tasks right through to today. Dunno, maybe this will help: http://nemesis.lonestar.org/computers/tandy/software/apps/m4/qd/opcodes.html

Comment: +1 just for being a z80 question.  Good times.

Comment: Heh... haven't touched it since the Spectrum either (much preferred it to the register-starved 6502). Carl's edited answer looks right from what I remember, though I can't vote it up now, having already vote-changed over the BC order issue. Ah well.

Comment: ZX-80? You sissies! I had a TRS-80 Model I Level II with full blown 16KB of mem! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do it directly.  You need to copy A into a 16-bit register pair and then do the add:

```
LD  B, 0
LD  C, A
ADC HL, BC
```

Comment: Yea I think that works.. but shouldn't B be 0 and C be A, not the other way around? (wait now it doesn't work anymore since 'ld bc, a' isn't valid)

Comment: Yeah, quite possibly.  Sorry don't remember the right order off the top of my head.  Edited back.

Comment: Oh i think it should be add, not adc

Comment: I thought you wanted with Carry?

Comment: C holds the lower byte, B the higher byte. So, yeah, B should be the zero.

Comment: @James: which is exactly as asked.

Comment: For posterity: make sure to compare this to James's answer below (**`add a,l \ ld l,a \ adc a,h \ sub l \ ld h,a`**) which is faster (20 cycles < 22 cycles), uses fewer registers, works more generally (for `BC += A` or `DE += A`), but is one byte longer.

Answer (score 29):

I would like to point out that the checked response (by Carl Norum) is correct, but not the best answer.
The following shows the speed of the two strategies with clock cycles.
Using the right solution saves time, and won't destroy a second 16 bit register pair.

```
  4   ld c,a            4   add a,l
  7   ld b,0            4   ld l,a
  11  add hl,bc         4   adc a,h
                        4   sub l
                        4   ld h,a
```

However, the solution on the right does take an extra byte of code.

Comment: I don't agree with the statement "fastest=best". Memory is usually an expensive resource on such machines. Hence "uses one more byte" is an important downside. OTOH, the "saves one register" argument is a nice one. Up to the OP to make his pick

Comment: Good point. I should have said "is not *necessarily* the best answer".

Comment: Registers can be a *very* precious resource though, so not using another 2 extra registers is a big win too.

Answer (score -4):

From http://nemesis.lonestar.org/computers/tandy/software/apps/m4/qd/opcodes.html

```
Add Byte with Carry-In Instructions
8080 Mnemonic Z80 Mnemonic  Machine Code Operation
ADC  M        ADC A,(HL)    8E           A <- A + (HL) + Carry
```

Comment: This is adding the contents of an 8 bit memory location to the 8 bit accumulator A.

Comment: `(HL)` means the *contents* of the byte address pointed to by HL, though... I don't *think* that's what the OP is trying to do.